# Count the number of cells used in a sum

Tags: excel

Suppose I have a discontinuous range of cells from a single column in a `SUM` formula (ie., `SUM(A1:A3, A5)`, is there formula I can use that will tell me that 4 cells are being used in that sum, or tell me the number of cells being used in a sum in general? I'd like to have the sum formula result and in the cell next to it the number of cells being used by the sum. I'd prefer an approach without using VBA if possible.

EDIT: I wasn't as specific as I should have been and for that I apologize. Using `SUM(A1:A3,A5)` again, let's say this formula exists in cell `A7`. Is there an Excel formula or function I can use to refer to cell `A7` which yields the number of cells it's using in the sum? I know I can use the `COUNT` function to accomplish this, but I'm trying to make this dynamic so that the formula I'm looking for depends of the number of cells being summed and every time there is a change in the number of cells being summed, this other formula or function detects it automatically.

Comment: If your sum formula is actually `=SUM(A:A)` and it is summing those 4 cells because they are the only ones that are numbers, you could simply do a count to get the number of cells that are numbers with `=COUNT(A:A)` which would result in 4 given your provided sample data

Comment: Use `COUNTA` if `A1 to A5` is not formula based.

Comment: Also `COUNT(A1:A3,A5)` is also valid.

Comment: In answer to your edit, no there is not.  You can use indirect and put the range in another cell as a string then refer to that cell using INDIRECT with both formula, but no there is no formula that will look at the formula in another cell and return the number of cells to which the first refers.

Comment: @ScottCraner I see. I'll have to come up with some alternative. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With a **continuous range**, you can get the total cell count *(used cells and empty cells)* with something like:

```
=COUNTA(A1:B9)+COUNTBLANK(A1:B9)
```

but `=COUNTBLANK()` won't support **discontinuous** ranges, so use:

```
=COUNTA(A1:A3, A5)+SUM(COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT({"A1:A3","A5"})))
```

*(I know it is ugly.)*

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Much appreciated. I'm afraid I may not have been clear enough on what I'm trying to accomplish, so I included an edit in the OP to further clarify.